# RxJS Resolve Error When Building Angular 2 with WebPack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am getting the following error when building my Angular 2 application with Webpack:

> ERROR in `./~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` Module not found: Error
>
> Cannot resolve module 'rxjs/Subject' in
>   `C:\...\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles`
>
> @ `./~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` 7:84-107

Here is my package.json:

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  }
}
```

And my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/modules/app/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: './src/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.ts?$/, 
                loader: 'ts-loader' 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that my Angular 2 application lives in the folder `/src/modules/app/main.ts`.

Why is Webpack having trouble resolving the `RxJS` dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing `.js` extension inside your `resolve` for webpack config and because of it you are getting `Module not found` for `core.umd.js`:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js' , '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts']
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the concise and clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Subject:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```